# k8s watch server containers

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, containers

Is there a way to get notified (like webhooks or sth like this?) about container changes in java?

Like, whenever a container shutdown, I still wanna get a "webhook".

Thanks for any contribution and ideas.

Comment: Thanks! So, you mean scheduled checks?

Answer (score 2):

Use Kubernetes API and watch for changes of your container/pod.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#efficient-detection-of-changes